# Transformar 2600 em 26.00 no PHP?

Tags: php, number-format

Terei valores como 2600 ou 15000 e preciso colocar como 26.00, 150.00, etc. Como posso fazer isso no PHP ? Com a função `number_format` ele coloca errado (no meu caso) como 2600,00 ou 15.000,00. Como posso fazer ?

Comment: Explique melhor o que você quer, porque é matemática bem básica, é só dividir por 100, depois você faz o que quiser.

Comment: Tão simples né @bigown. Fiz essa divisão por 100 e deu certo :)

Comment: Estuprando a lógica.

Answer (score 1):

Faça o seguinte:

```
<?php
$number = "15000";
echo number_format($number, 0, ',', '.');
?>
```

Assim ele vai retornar: 15.000

Comment: Isso está errado cara, o número deve vir na quantia correta e você só vai adicionar os decimais usando o number_format mesmo. Se ele está vindo com zero a mais pode considerar isso um bug.